# Send GameCenter friendrequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center

At the moment I'm working on a iPhone app and I have a problem.
I want, that the player can send a gamecenter friendrequest.

In the apple Guide there are two methods I'm interested in.
The first would be

```
- (void)addRecipientsWithPlayerIDs:(NSArray *)playerids
```

and the second would be

```
- (void)setMessage:(NSString *)message
```

Now I don't know to put them in the right order to get on.
How can I set the player ID's and the message, and after that, how can I send the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have player ids in `friendsArray`. Then try this:

```
GKFriendRequestComposeViewController *friendRequestViewController = [[GKFriendRequestComposeViewController alloc] init];
friendRequestViewController.composeViewDelegate = self;
[friendRequestViewController setMessage:@"Add your message here"];
if (friendsArray)
{
    [friendRequestViewController addRecipientsWithPlayerIDs: friendsArray];
}
[self presentModalViewController: friendRequestViewController animated: YES];
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Thank's for your quick response. Yes the PlayerID's I already have in a array. I'll try it in 6 houres when I get home.

Comment: Sure, but by this time I might be on my way home from office. btw let me know. :P

Comment: Almost everthing works, but addRecipientsWithPlayers: friendsArray doesn't work. I checked if the Array is empty, but when I test it with NSLog(@"%@", friendsArray); it shows me the content of the array. The message works perfect.

Comment: @user3579917> But what?

Comment: The friendRequestcontroller appears with the right text, but the array doesn't put the names into the friendrequestcontroller.